# Delay componentDidMount fetch for this.props to be read

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching `data` from within `componentDidMount` as

```
this.setState({ isLoading: true });
fetch(
  `https://api.example.com/location/12345`
)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
    }
  })
  .then(data => this.setState({ data, isLoading: false }));
```

and this works absolutely fine. But if I want to replace `https://api.example.com/location/12345` with `https://api.example.com/location/${this.props.id}` to allow the `id` to change I get back errors that the data does not exist.

This is clearly because the `fetch` inside `componentDidMount` is fetching the url before before the `this.props.id` is read.

How can I delay the `fetch` until `this.props.id` is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is, use [**componentDidUpdate**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method to get the data whenever component receive new id, but make sure to compare the prev id value with new id value and do the call only when they are not same.

Like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.id && (prevProps.id != this.props.id)) {
        this._getData();
    }
}

_getData(){
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch(
        `https://api.example.com/location/${this.props.id}`
    )
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
        }
    })
    .then(data => this.setState({ data, isLoading: false }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason this isn't working for me but I think it perhaps is because I am using `gatsby` v2 and now using `reach-router`.

Comment: are you getting any error? if you explain the issue, i will try to help you :)

Comment: No, but if I `console.log(data)` it's undefined,

Comment: call the same method on a button click and check, also do `console.log(this.props.id)` inside `_getData` and verify the value.

Comment: I don't think `location` is being read as to identify `prevProps`

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern quite often :

```
initFromProps(props: MyComponentProps) {
  const {  } = props;
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.initFromProps(this.props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: MyComponentProps) {
  this.initFromProps(nextProps);
}
```

This ensures your component does whatever is necessary when the props change, but also at startup. Then, in `initFromProps`, you can do something along the lines of this:

```
initFromProps(props: MyComponentProps) {
  const { id } = props;

  if (id !== this.props.id) {
    this._getData(id);
  }

}
```

Comment: and both these methods will be deprecated in new version, in 16.3 they are available with **UNSAFE_** prefix. Check this [**doc article**](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html), so better to not suggest these methods. :)

Comment: componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps are deprecated